# ArrayList - Remove the first added object and no repeats

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm doing an assignment where I have to add a Present to an ArrayList of presents. There can be a maximum of 10 presents in the ArrayList and the present is defined by its type, cost and name, and if these three fields are the same, then it's the same present and it cannot be added to the ArrayList.

When an eleventh present is added, the first present added to the list has to be removed and this new present take its place.

And I'm really stuck.

This is my code so far:

```
public class GiftList 

{

       private ArrayList<Present> presents;

       public GiftList() {
              presents = new ArrayList<Present>();
       }

       public void addPresent(Present present) {
       if (presents.size() <= 10) {
              presents.add(present);
       }
       else {
              //**Remove oldest present in list, then
              presents.add(present);
       }
       //**Another if statement for no duplicated presents
}

public class Present
{
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private double cost;

    public Present(String name, String type, double cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.cost = cost;
    }
}
```

Comment: "_And I'm really stuck._" With which part exactly? Explain what you tried and what didn't work about it.

Comment: If theres a "Maximum of 10", it should be `< 10`, not `<= 10`.

Comment: Do you have to use an ArrayList or could you possibly use e.g. a `Set`

Comment: @wassgren brings up a good point -- a Set would work much better because then your duplicate values are taken care of automatically.  Did your instructor *specify* that you need to use an ArrayList?  Or would he be willing to let you use any kind of collection (i.e. not just a List, but a Set)?  Academia is weird sometimes.  In the real world you would use a LinkedHashSet, but in the artificial confines of the classroom you may be required to use an ArrayList.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

- Look on [how to implement](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html) [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) for `Present`.
- Check: [`List.remove(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)) and [`List.contains(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)).

Answer (score 1):

If you add an `equals` method to your `Present` object:

```
public class Present {
    private double cost;
    private String name;
    private String type;

    public Present(String name, String type, double cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Present) {
            Present p2 = (Present) o;
            return name.equals(p2.name) && type.equals(p2.type) && Double.valueOf(cost).equals(p2.cost);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, type, cost);
    }
}
```

Then the following code could be used:

```
List<Present> myList = new ArrayList<Present>() {
    @Override
    public boolean add(final Present present) {
        if (contains(present)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (size() >= 10) {
            remove(0);
        }
        return super.add(present);
    }
};

myList.add(new Present("name", "type", 1.0));
```

For more info, see [Object.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [List.remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)).

However, I believe the best way to do this would be to either use a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) which automatically handles the *no repeats*-problem or some kind of [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html). If some kind of hash-solution is used  (e.g. a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)) don't forget to implement the `hashCode` function (more info on hashCode [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())).

Edit: added the `hashCode`-implementation after input from @ TJamesBoone.

Comment: Even though you can get away with overriding `equals()` but not `hashCode()` if you're using an ArrayList for purposes of a solution, you should still override `hashCode()` regardless.  Otherwise, your `Present` class will be in violation of the equals-hashCode contract.

Comment: @TJamesBoone - agreed. I just removed it to make the code *shorter*. `hashCode` is described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()).

Answer (score 0):

you can just remove the first element by calling

```
presents.remove(0);
```

check this
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_remove.htm

For duplication it would be better if you used a `Set`

But, if you stick with ArrayList, then implement equals/hashcode as already mentioned and now there are 
two options:

1. Either always call remove (for the new object) before adding it, so it always removes oldest entries
2. or check existence before adding.

Although 2nd option might be more efficient it depends on how you want to utilize your queue (how FIFO is defined for duplicated objects?). If a new object already exists in the list, do you want to update its index, as it was a new entry? if yes you update its status and it will be deleted at a later time than keeping the older one.

Comment: The assignment specifies ArrayList, but set is better for duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your description I think this could do your job

```
int rotatingIndex =- 1 ; //variable maintaining current value of the index.-1 when no elements are         present
public void addPresent(Present present) {
    rotatingIndex = (rotatingIndex + 1)%10;
    presents.add(rotatingIndex,present);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to override equals for Present, and use linkedlist as queue. like;

```
public class Present
{
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private Double cost;


    public Present(String name, String type, Double cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.cost = cost;
    }



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }



    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }



    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }



    public Double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }



    public void setCost(Double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(obj == null || !(obj instanceof Present)){
        return false;
        }

        Present anotherPresent = (Present) obj;
        if(this.getName() == anotherPresent.getName() 
                && this.getCost() == anotherPresent.getCost() 
                && this.getType() == anotherPresent.getType()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Gift class:

```
public class GiftList 

{

       private LinkedList<Present> presents = new LinkedList() ;

       public void addPresent(Present present) {
       if (presents.contains(present)){
           // do nothing it already exists!!
           return ;
       }
       if(presents.size() <= 10) {
              presents.add(present);
       }
       else {
            presents.pop();
              //**Remove oldest present in list, then
              presents.add(present);
       }
       //**Another if statement for no duplicated presents
}
}
```